# Julia power operator not working as expected

Tags: julia

I'm just experimenting with Julia and found that it gives incorrect value when run:

**Input:**

```
println(1000^6)
println(1000^7)
println(1000^8)
println(1000^9)
```

**Output:**

```
1000000000000000000
3875820019684212736
2003764205206896640
-6930898827444486144
```

Is this an issue or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: that's due to integer overflow, use `BigInt` instead: `println(BigInt(1000)^7)`, I believe this question is dup.

Comment: You can read about integer overflow, and why Julia chose this path here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/faq/#Why-does-Julia-use-native-machine-integer-arithmetic?-1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained the problem is due to integer overflow. Maximum value you can store in an Int64 can be obtained thanks to

```
julia> typemax(Int64)
9223372036854775807
```

However, `1000^9` is bigger, as you can see with:

```
julia> BigInt(1000)^9
1000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: So, basically `BigInt` is also a `DataType` like `Int64` or `Float64` but don't have max limit i.e. `typemax(BigInt)` won't work.

Comment: Int64 or Float64 are [primitive types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/types/#Primitive-Types-1). BigInt is a `mutable struct`(see [gmp.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/2d90358b14830beb6aef975eea0009bf01973b44/base/gmp.jl) source code). Its memory footprint grows on demand. Under the hood it uses the [gmp](https://gmplib.org/) library.